# Nested if is not working in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, djcelery

I am trying to doing a project using nested if. But it's not working. why?
My code is,

```
schedule = Schedule.objects.all()
    for c in schedule :
        p = c.poll
        e = c.end_time
        s = c.start_time
        n = c.no_of_response
        now = timezone.now()
        #phn = Response.objects.filter(poll = p).exclude(sid = 'Null').count()
        if (c.start_time <= now) & (now <= c.end_time):
            if n == 0:
                c.poll.status='Running'
                c.poll.save()
```

Comment: What is not working? Please provide more information.

Comment: You haven't included any information about what `no_of_response` is, (i'll leave my answer there because I still think that is a mistake)

Comment: if (c.start_time <= now) & (now <= c.end_time):
   c.poll.status='Running'
   c.poll.save()                                                                                   This code is working. But when I put nested if, that is if n==0: , inside the first if condition, then the whole code is not working. Why this happened?

Comment: It is working, but `n` is never 0, and as I mention above, you haven't included any information about what `no_of_response` *is*

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a bit comparison with `&`, you probably want to use `and` (or `&&`)

```
(c.start_time <= now) and (now <= c.end_time)
```

or better yet

```
c.start_time <= now <= c.end_time
```

Comment: This code is correct. But doesn't check the if n==0: . Why? Sorry for my bad english

Comment: @naveen - Probably because that never evaluates for true for whatever reason, you might want to try using `datetime.now()` instead

Comment: This code is working.                                                                                    if (c.start_time <= now) & (now <= c.end_time):
   c.poll.status='Running'
   c.poll.save()